# Generating link tag for nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink, routes

I have the following routes:

```
   namespace :gallery do
      resources :collections, only: [:index, :show] do
         resources :albums, only: [:index, :show] do
            resources :photos, only: :show
         end
      end
   end
```

and am trying to link to a Photo Show page from an Album Show page. I have tried all sorts of things but I can't get any of the helpers to generate the correct link.

Album Show:

```
<div class="container--padded">
  <div class="home-intro">
    <h1><%= @album.title %></h1>
    <div class="grid">
      <% @photos.each do |photo| %>
         <div class="grid__item grid__item--photo flex-embed flex-embed--1by1">
            <div class="flex-embed__item">
               <% @dimensions = FastImage.size(photo.source(:small)) %>
               <img src="<%= image_path(photo.source(:small)) %>" class="<%= @dimensions[0] > @dimensions[1] ? 'landscape' : 'portrait' %>" />
               <%= link_to 'Photo', gallery_collection_album_photo_path(photo) %>
            </div>
         </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas how I can fix the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass all nested objects as parameter to the url helper, i.e.

```
gallery_collection_album_photo_path(@collection, @album, photo)
```

`url_for` should work as well:

```
url_for([@collection, @album, photo])
```